# Bootstrap 3 Grid System

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am migrating a project of mine from bootstrap 2 to bootstrap 3. Now, I am having some problem with the grid layout that I can't understand. I have a col-md-12 and I wanna add 3 columns of equal width in this larger div. Logically, the 3 columns should each be col-md-4. However, when I add the 3 columns (divs) of class col-md-4, they don't fit and one of them gets pushed down and some space is left at the end after the 2nd one. 
Please someone help me understand something that I may be missing. Thank you.

Comment: This may be varying from site to site, depending on jQuery Plugins and custom CSS. Please give us more Information to work with.

Comment: @Denny, it sounds like you're probably using extra padding-left or padding-right on some of your columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is padding.  Bootstrap automatically adds padding when you have nested `col-xx-#` classes.  If you have `col-md-4` as a direct child of a `col-md-12` bootstrap will add padding and your third `col-md-4` will end up on a new line.

What you're doing:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 1/3
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 2/3
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 3/3
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To address this, either add a new `class="row"` above your first `col-md-4` or simply remove the `col-md-12` like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
             1/3
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
             2/3
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
             3/3
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's column layout can only be 12 "units" in width.

To archieve columns of equal width, you should split 12 equally (sum of * in col-md-* should be 12).

Comment: Denny says right in his question..." I have a col-md-12 and I wanna add 3 columns of equal width in this larger div. Logically, the 3 columns should each be col-md-4.", so I don't think this is the problem.